# Why doesn't this code output the numbered i entered?

Tags: assembly, x86-16, emu8086

the code just takes an input and prints it, while i am debugging i noticed that AL is never filled with the value i give it , the emu8086 always put $$ in the value of AL, wHY ?

```
    org 100h

.MODEL SMALL
.DATA
MSG DB "ENTER A NUMBER: $"
MSG2 DB "HERE IS YOUR NUMBER: $"
.CODE
MAIN PROC
    
    MOV AX, @DATA
    MOV DS, AX
    
    MOV AH, 09h; display the message to take user input
    LEA DX, MSG
    INT 21H
    
    MOV AH, 01h ;take user input and put it in AL
    INT 21H
    mov BL, AL ; move it from AL to BL
    sub BL,48h ; sub 48 to change from ASCII to decimal
    
    ;print msg2 and print AL VALUE
    MOV AH, 09h
    LEA DX, MSG2
    INT 21H
     
    mov DL,BL 
    MOV AH, 02h
    INT 21H      
 
ret
```

Comment: _"the emu8086 always put $$ in the value of AL"_ Which point during execution are we talking about here? Note that after execution of `int 21h / ah=09h`, the value of `al` will be `'$'` (i.e. the string terminator character).

Comment: It's counterproductive to convert to decimal if you want to print it as ascii again. At which point did you see the `$` in `al`? Note that printing via `int 21/09` does leave the terminating `$` in `al` so if you checked it at the wrong location (not after the input) then you may be seeing that.

Comment: If you delete the `sub bl, 48h` the code works as expected.

Comment: BTW for conversion between numbers 0..9 and the corresponding ASCII digits "0" .. "9'" we need to add/subtract 48 **decimal** alias 30h alias "0".

Comment: Thanks to everyone who commented i actually got it working :D virtual hug

Comment: also something weird was happening..whenever i entered a number form the "number keypad" on the right side of the keyboard, the number wouldn't show up in the display,but when i click the number keys above the letters it actually does display....weird(i'm running it on linux)

Comment: @hackeronemember You need to have *NumLock* turned on to use the digits from the separate keypad. There's a keyboard LED for that also.